# Show that $f(x,y,z)=(x-y)^n+(y-z)^n+(z-x)^n$ is divisible by $(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that $f(x,y,z)=(x-y)^n+(y-z)^n+(z-x)^n$ is divisible by $(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)$

This is a particular case where $n=6k±1$.We can write the divisor as:

$x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz=(x+\omega y+\omega^2z)(x+\omega^2y+\omega z)$

Where $1$, $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ are cubic roots of unity.  We put $x=-\omega y-\omega^2 z$ in $f(x,y,z)$ and we get $f(x,y,z)=0$.This is for when $n=6k-1$

For  $n=6k+1$  the derivative of $f(x,y,z)$  on x is also  zero for $x=-\omega y-\omega^2 z$, therefore $f(x,y,z)$ is divisible by $(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz)^2$

For example:

$(x-y)^5+(y-z)^5+(z-x)^5=5(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz)$

$(x-y)^7+(y-z)^7+(z-x)^7=7(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz)^2$

Generally we can write:

If $n=6k-1$, then:

$(x-y)^n+(y-z)^n+(z-x)^n=n(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz)$

If $n=6k+1$, then:

$(x-y)^n+(y-z)^n+(z-x)^n=n(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz)^2$

If $n=2^t(6k±1)$, then $a^n=(a^{2t})^{6k±1}$ and $f(x,y,z)$ can be factorized, but I do not think it can be factorized if $n=2^t$.

Is there simpler way to show this?

Comment: Before simplifying we need to get the correct statement and argument. For example, for $n=2^1$ we have that $f(x,y,z)=f_n(x,y,z)=2(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)$. However, for $n=3$ $f_3(x,y,z)$ is not a multiple of $g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx$. In general, you can do the susbstitution that you did, $x=-wy-w^2z$. Then de-homogenize the polynomial $f(-wy-w^2z,y,z)$ by dividing by $z^n$ and calling $t=y/z$. Looking at the constant term $(-w)^{n}+(-1)^n+(-w)^n$ tells you that if $3$ divides $n$, then $g$ doesn't divide $f_n$.

Comment: If $3$ doesn't divide $n$, then taking successive derivatives of the de-homogenized polynomial in $t$ above, and evaluating at zero, we can verify that that polynomial is identically zero. We need to do the same for the other factor $x+w^2y+wz$ too.

Comment: You can use remainder and factor theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Note first that $x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx=((x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2)/2.$

We have:

**Theorem 1**:
For all positive integers $n>1$ with $3\not|n$
$$(X-Y)^n+(Y-Z)^n+(Z-X)^n=R^{'}(X-Y,Y-Z)(X^2+Y^2+Z^2-XY-YZ-ZX)^{r(n)}$$
with $R^{'}(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, homogeneous of degree $n-2$ and $r(n)=2$ if $3|n-1$, $r(n)=1$ otherwise.

We have the following lemma:

Let $f_n(x)=x^n+1+(-1-x)^n$ then $1+x+x^2$ divides $f_n(x)$ over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ for all positive integers $n>1$ if and only if $3\not|n$.

In addition $1+x+x^2$ divides $f_n^{'}(x)$ iff $3|n-1$ and hence $(1+x+x^2)^2$ divides $f_n(x)$ over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ iff $3|n-1$.

**Proof of lemma**:

$1+x+x^2$ has complex conjugate roots given by $w^3=1$, $w\neq1$.

We have $f_n(w)=w^n+1+(1+w)^n=w^n+1+(-1-w)^n=w^n+1+(w^2)^n=1+w^n+w^{2n}$. Clearly since $w^3=1$, $f_n(w)=0\iff3\not|n$. Hence $1+x+x^2=(x-w)(x-\bar w)|f_n(w)\iff3\not|n$.

$f_n^{'}(x)=nx^{n-1}-n(-1-x)^{n-1}=n(x^{n-1}-(-1-x)^{n-1})$. Hence $f_n^{'}(w)=n(w^{n-1}-(w^2)^{n-1})=n(w^{n-1}-w^{2(n-1)})=0 \iff 3|(n-1)$. Hence $1+x+x^2=(x-w)(x-\bar w)|f_n^{'}(w)\iff3|n-1$. Since in this case we have  $1+x+x^2$ divides both $f_n(x)$ and $f_n^{'}(x)$ we can deduce that $(1+x+x^2)^2$ divides $f_n(x) \iff3|n-1$.

$\blacksquare$

**Proof of Theorem 1**:

By the lemma, for $3\not|n$ we have $x^n+1+(-1-x)^n=R(x)(1+x+x^2)^{r(n)}$ where $R(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree $n-2$ and $r(n)=2$ if $3|n-1$, $r(n)=1$ otherwise.

Hence substituting $x/y$ for $x$ we obtain $$(x/y)^n+1+(-1-(x/y))^n=R(x/y)((1+(x/y)^2+(1+(x/y))^2)/2)^{r(n)}.$$ Multiplying through by $y^n$ we have $$x^n+y^n+(-x-y)^n=R^{'}(x,y)((x^2+y^2+(x+y)^2)/2)^{r(n)}.$$ with $R^{'}(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, homogeneous of degree $n-2$. Substituting $x=X-Y$, $y=Y-Z$ we obtain:$$(X-Y)^n+(Y-Z)^n+(Z-X)^n=R^{'}(X-Y,Y-Z)(((X-Y)^2+(Y-Z)^2+(Z-X)^2)/2)^{r(n)}=R^{'}(X-Y,Y-Z)(X^2+Y^2+Z^2-XY-YZ-ZX)^{r(n)}$$
$\blacksquare$

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think you missed '+' in first line before $(x-z)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

I think "OP" @ Sirous has rediscovered what

was known a while ago. Tito Piezas has shown

in his online book "Collection of Algebraic

Identities". As mentioned below:

{Define $(a,b,w) = [(xy), (x+y), (x^2+xy+y^2)]$.  Then,

$(x+y)^5 - x^5 - y^5 = 5abw$

$(x+y)^7 - x^7 - y^7 = 7abw^2$

$(x+y)^{11} - x^{11} - y^{11} = 11abw(a^2b^2+w^3)$

$(x+y)^{13} - x^{13} - y^{13} = 13abw^2(2a^2b^2+w^3)$

$(x+y)^{17} - x^{17} - y^{17} = 17abw(a^4b^4+5a^2b^2w^3+w^6)$

$(x+y)^{19} - x^{19} - y^{19} = 19abw^2(3a^2b^2+7a^2b^2w^3+w^6)$

[Note the slight difference's on (RHS) of equation,

between exponent's having primes of form $(6k-1)$ and $(6k+1)$]

If "OP" substitutes, $(x,y)=[(a-b),(b-c)]$, he will get,

(LHS) as $[(a-b)^n+(b-c)^n+(c-a)^n]$  and,

$ w=(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$

Since '$w$' is a common factor in the above

Identities it means '$w$' divides the (LHS) for

equation's having exponent's with primes of

the form $(6k-1)$ & $(6k+1)$.

For, k=1,2,3  we get the primes (5,7,11,13,17,19)

The link to Tito's article is given below.

https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/001a